# Special redirect for external iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, iframe

I have a "main.html" and a little iframe with content from the external "content.html".

My plan: if someone load the external "content.html" directly, the user should automaticly redirect to the "main.html", but this redirect should not work if the "content.html" is shown in an iframe. And I also dont want to forbid the direct load - i need the automaticly redirect.

Is that possible? Any simple, universal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JavaScript redirect, that only activates if the window is in an iframe:

```
if (window == window.top) {
    window.location = 'main.html';
}
```